# Recommend any good real-time web services?

Tags: web-services, rest

I'm working on a real-time app and looking for some good data sources to test with as input, but I can't seem to find any publicly available services I can hook into - any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try [WebServiceX.NET](http://www.webservicex.net/ws/default.aspx). You could use their [Currency Converter](http://webservicex.net/ws/WSDetails.aspx?CATID=2&WSID=10)